# What to do with Very Low Quality flags in the review queues for answers that are really Not an Answer?

Tags: discussion, moderation, flagging

I have noticed a few answers showing up in the review queues lately which were flagged as *Very Low Quality*, but which were clearly *Not an Answer* since the posted answers were actually questions themselves. [Here is a recent example](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/74294/39614).

I clicked on *Looks OK*, left a comment under the answer for flaggers pointing out that the correct flag is *Not an Answer*, and then flagged the question as *Not an Answer* myself, in hopes that the original flagger or flaggers would see the comment and consider their flags more carefully.

Was this a reasonable course of action, and does it even matter which flag we choose in these circumstances given the the outcome should probably be deletion anyway?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there's no "Not an Answer" review queue. Both "Not an Answer" and "Very Low Quality" flags will go into "Low Quality Posts" review queues.

So, yeah, unfortunately, in this case, [your action of choosing "Looks OK"](https://music.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/43247) was wrong since it contradicted your real intent.

There's even a canned response for "This is a different question posted as an answer" when choosing Delete from "Low Quality Posts" review queue:

> If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: If it's 'not an answer' how can it 'look OK'?